# Method calling sequence is changed in IOS 6.0 and IOS 5.0

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios6

I am running one Application for ios 6.0 and ios 5.0 but few methods are calling in different sequence for both of the version. I am not getting what is the issue. This is console log for iOS 6.0
Two-stage rotation animation is deprecated. This application should use the smoother single-stage animation.

```
2012-12-15 18:20:23.111 Testl3675:22803] ADDRESPONSE - ADDING TO MEMORY ONLY: http://gsp1.apple.com/pep/gcc
2012-12-15 18:20:23.670 Test[3675:1d903] View did load
2012-12-15 18:20:23.724 Test[3675:1d903] Download Notification----------
2012-12-15 18:20:23.773 Test[3675:1d903] Loaded explore view
2012-12-15 18:20:23.793 Test[3675:1d903] IntegrationManager initialized
```

And here is ios 5.0 console log

```
2012-12-15 18:29:44.828 Test[3760:15e03] IntegrationManager initialized
```

Anyone knows why this is happening?

Comment: i believe third partly application uses different programming for iOS 5 and iOS 6 ..that is what should show this behavior

Comment: dont get this question at all. the general calling sequence is unchanged I would highly assume :D

Comment: It is real question not fake

Comment: I'm seeing this exact ADDRESPONSE message as well, so you're not seeing things, iProgrammer. It does not appear in any third party libraries, from what I can tell. Are you doing anything with MapKit perchance? It's hard to know what code to post in this case, but it seems to be occurring during viewDidLoad:, and all on the main thread.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547490/log-messages-i-didnt-asked-for-in-xcode-4-5-with-ios-6-0

Comment: The ADDRESPONSE thing is nothing to worry about.  The two-stage rotation thing happens (so far as I've seen) when you place a TabBarController inside a NavigationController.

Answer (score 3):

I got that message, and that was because in

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
     // my implementation
}
```

is WRONG.

To fix this, I did this:
    -(void) viewDidLoad {
         // my implementation
         [super viewDidLoad];
    }

Comment: I mean, add [super viewDidLoad] AFTER implementation, not before