# Addresponse - adding to memory only (XCode)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I'm trying to connect my project to a php file but every time this shows:

```
ADDRESPONSE - ADDING TO MEMORY ONLY
```

I have never seen it before.
this is the code i Use:

```
//Gets the php
FindURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://domain.com/Myfile.php?username=%@", Username.text];
// to execute php code
URLData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:FindURL]];

// to receive the returend value
DataResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:URLData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"%@",DataResult);
```

What can i do?

Thanks in advance

Update code:

```
- (IBAction)UpdateList:(id)sender{



    NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://domain.com/Myfile.php"]
        cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
        timeoutInterval:15.0];
    NSURLConnection *Connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if (Connection) {
        //Connect
    }else{
        //Error
    }

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
    DataResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"%@", DataResult);

}
```

Comment: please have a look at this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547490/log-messages-i-didnt-asked-for-in-xcode-4-5-with-ios-6-0

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same issue - check out the following, this might help you:
[Log Messages I didn't asked for in Xcode 4.5 with iOS 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547490/log-messages-i-didnt-asked-for-in-xcode-4-5-with-ios-6-0)

I haven't found a solution so far, but since I now know that this Log is produced by the OS, I no longer look for its origin in my source :)

Comment: I have begun seeing these messages too. I suspect that in my case it's related to Burstly (now called SkyRocket). Are you guys using Burstly?

Comment: No, I'm not using Burstly/SkyRocket. Has anyone seen those messages in iOS7?

Comment: I just saw this with Xcode 5 and iOS 7. No Burstly/SkyRocket here.

Answer (score 0):

I got this log by making an `NSURLRequest` to an invalid URL. My app is supposed to show a `UIAlertView` when it catches an error on the server side, so I asked our system admin to take our entire site down so I can see what happens. He declined my request, so I typed random letters and put a `.com` at the end of the request URL.

Turns out we have an internal test server that doesn't seem to be accessible from my WiFi connection, so when I changed the URL to that instead, the log stopped appearing.

Comment: “so I asked our system admin to take our entire site down so I can see what happens. He declined my request”. LOL.